# Duda acerca algoritmo de desencolar con templates

Tags: c++, template

Tengo un situacion con una cola que hice con templates

Cuando lleno la cola con datos y despues  cuando desencolo un elemento ya no puedo volver a ingresar ningun elemento, porque me dice que la cola esta llena

Este es el header 
https://pastebin.com/Qdq9W9C8

Esta es la funcion que desencola

```
template <class T>
int Cola<T>::operator -(T *Dato)
{
/* La variable Res se inicializa en 0 (fracaso). Si la eliminación se
lleva a cabo, entonces se le asignará el valor de 1 (éxito). */
int Res = 0;
int i;

if (!ColaVacia())
{
    *Dato = EspacioCola[Frente];
    if (Frente == Final)
    {
        Frente = -1;
        Final  = -1;
    }
    else
        Frente++;            
    Res = 1;
}
return Res;
 }
```

https://pastebin.com/M5hLK9JX

Este es el main este llama a la funcion de esta manera

```
  case 2:
            if(Deposito - &Prod)
            {
                cout << Prod;
                Total = Total+Prod.RegresaPrecio();
            }
            else
                cout<<"\n\tNo se encuentran productos en el deposito !!!\n";
            break;
```

Tengo entendido que el indicados "Final" de la cola se tiene que mover para dar espacio, ¿pero como hago eso ?

Comment: no utilizes pastebin.com, publica todo el codigo aca. Los links para mañana ya estaran muertos y nadie podra ayudarte

Answer (score 2):

Con el código incompleto y sin indicarnos cuál es tu colección de datos sólo podemos jugar a las adivinanzas.

---

#### Tu interfaz es terrible.

**El operador de resta binaria es la peor elección que podías hacer**.

La interfaz con la que se accede a los métodos de tu clase plantilla `Cola` atenta gravemente contra el [principio de la mínima sorpresa](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_la_M%C3%ADnima_Sorpresa). Aparentemente para desencolar un objeto de tu cola, usas el operador de resta binaria (binaria porque recibe dos operadores, uno a cada lado), lo cuál ya es terriblemente contraintuitivo para empezar, pero lo empeoras al utilizar un puntero al dato en lugar del dato en si.

El operador binario de resta no modifica ninguno de los datos sobre los que es aplicado, veámoslo con un ejemplo:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 2;
int c = a - b;
```

En el código anterior, se aplica el operador binario de resta sobre las variables enteras `a` y `b` y se guarda el resultado en la variable entera `c`, tras operar tenemos los siguientes valores:

```
std::cout << a << ' ' << b << ' ' << c; // Muestra 2 2 0
```

Como puedes ver, el operador de resta (`-`) binario **no ha modificado las variables `a` o `b`**. En cambio en tu código, la instrucción:

```
if(Deposito - &Prod)
```

El operador modifica la variable a su izquierda (`Deposito`) lo cuál va en contra de lo que cabe esperar de ese tipo de operador (atentando contra el principio de la mínima sorpresa).

**Usa otro operador o mejor: usa una función miembro**.

Si realmente quieres usar un operador, sobrecarga el operador `-=`:

```
template <class T>
int Cola<T>::operator -=(T *Dato)
//                    ^^ <--- Sabemos que este operador modifica el dato de la izquierda

if(Deposito -= &Prod)
// ^^^^^^^^^^^ <--- Queda clara la intencion de modificar Deposito
```

Pero no te lo aconsejo, puede parecerte muy claro y limpio el código usando operadores, pero si les das un significado diferente al que intuitivamente se conoce para los mismos harás que el código sea confuso para otros programadores; así pues: usa una función que deje claro cuál es su misión escogiendo para la misma un nombre claro y descriptivo:

```
template <class T>
bool Cola<T>::desencola(T *Dato)
{
    /* La variable Res se inicializa en false (fracaso). Si la eliminación se
    lleva a cabo, entonces se le asignará el valor de true (éxito). */
    int Res = false;

    // ....

    return Res;
}
```

Observarás que he cambiado el nombre de la función de desencolado (antes un operador) y este nuevo nombre no deja dudas de la misión que lleva a cabo, también he cambiado el retorno a booleano, ya que el resultado de desencolar sólo puede ser verdadero o falso.

**No pases un puntero**.

Tu `Cola` almacena datos, no punteros, así que desencolar un puntero es muy contraintuitivo, deberías cambiarlo por el dato que quieres desencolar:

```
template <class T>
bool Cola<T>::desencola(const T &Dato)
{
    /* La variable Res se inicializa en false (fracaso). Si la eliminación se
    lleva a cabo, entonces se le asignará el valor de true (éxito). */
    int Res = false;

    // ....

    return Res;
}
```

Observarás que he cambiado el tipo que recibe la función a `const T &` porque lo que quieres es eliminar el dato de tipo `T` contenido en tu `Cola` sin modificar el dato pasado.

#### Tu problema.

Un puntero es una dirección de memoria a una variable, dos variables diferentes que contienen el mismo valor, tendrán punteros diferentes. Dado que me falta contexto no puedo asegurar lo que voy a decir, pero creo que tu problema es que no estás desencolando nada, y no desencolas nada porque cuando le pasas el puntero a desencolar:

```
case 2:
    if(Deposito - &Prod)
```

Le pasas el puntero de una variable local que, evidentemente, no estará contenido en tu `Cola`.